# Input shape for Keras LSTM/GRU language model

Tags: python, nlp, keras, lstm, language-model

I am trying to train a language model on word level in Keras.

I have my X and Y, both with the shape (90582L, 517L)

When I try fit this model:

```
print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(GRU(512, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(90582, 517)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GRU(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributedDense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(x_pad, y_pad, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=2)
```

I get the error:

```
Exception: Error when checking model input: 
expected gru_input_7 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (90582L, 517L)
```

I need some guidance as to what the input shape should be? I've done trial and error on all sorts of combinations but it seems I am misunderstanding something fundamental.

In the Keras text generation example, the X matrix had 3 dimensions. I have no idea what the third dimension is supposed to be though.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you are trying to do. I guess that your data of shape (90582, 517) is a set of 90582 samples with 517 words each. If so, you have to transform your words into word vectors (=embeddings) in order for them to be meaningful. Then you will have the shape (90582, 517, embedding_dim), which can be handled by the GRU.

The [Keras Embedding layer](http://keras.io/layers/embeddings/) can do that for you. Add it as the first layer of your Neural Network before the fist GRU layer.

```
vocabulary_size = XXXXX     # give your vocabulary size here (largest word ID in the input)
embedding_dim = XXXX        # give your embedding dimension here (e.g. 100)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, embedding_dim, input_shape=(90582, 517)))
model.add(GRU(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(GRU(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributedDense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(x_pad, y_pad, batch_size=128, nb_epoch=2)
```